# Internationalizing Bash scripts

Tags: bash, ubuntu, internationalization, shell

I've been following a [tutorial](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/internationalizing-those-bash-scripts) from a recent edition of the *Linux Journal* which teaches how to internationalize Bash scripts. However, I'm having trouble getting it to work on my system (Ubuntu 10.04.) When I get to the part where I'm supposed to call "gettext," after setting the environment variable TEXTDOMAINDIR, I get:

```
toby@toby-laptop:~/Desktop/i18n$ gettext -s "Greeting"
Greeting
```

But it should be printing a message that says "Hello, I can generate a random number between 2 numbers that you provide" instead of just "Greeting." Can anybody replicate this problem? Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The author of that tutorial forgot the following step:

```
export TEXTDOMAIN=rand.sh
```

which should be performed when step shown as `export TEXTDOMAINDIR=/home/lji/locale` is done (substituting the appropriate directory name).

You can use `$""` instead of `gettext`:

```
$ cat rand.sh
#!/bin/bash
TEXTDOMAINDIR=$HOME/locale   # probably not the best place for these files, but OK for testing
TEXTDOMAIN=rand.sh
gettext -s "Greeting"
echo $"Greeting"
$ ./rand.sh
Hello, I can generate a random number between 2 numbers that you provide
Hello, I can generate a random number between 2 numbers that you provide
```

Note that the [Bash manual](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC13) says that some systems may make use of the variables `$LC_MESSAGES`, `$TEXTDOMAIN` and `$TEXTDOMAINDIR` in different ways.

Comment: what would be the best places for those files?

Comment: I would consider paralleling similar system-defined directories, so possible choices might be `/usr/local/locale`, `/usr/local/lib/locale` or `/usr/local/share/locale` or similar.